# Mysql query taking more time for large data

Tags: mysql, sql, database-administration

```
SELECT 
      product_id, 
      UPPER(identifier) as identifier, 
      date, 
      day, 
      metric, 
      count
   FROM
      ( SELECT 
              product_code as product_id, 
              session_ip_address as identifier, 
              DATE_FORMAT(day, '%d %b %Y') as date, 
              day, 
              "Event_SubSessions" as metric, 
              count(distinct session_id) as count
           FROM 
              tableA
           WHERE 
                  customer_id IN (?) 
              AND product_code = ? 
              AND day IN (?)
           GROUP BY 
              date, 
              identifier
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
              product_code as product_id, 
              session_ip_address as identifier, 
              DATE_FORMAT(day, '%d %b %Y') as date, 
              day, 
              metric, 
              sum(count) as count
           FROM 
              tableA
           WHERE 
                  customer_id IN (?) 
              AND product_code = ?
              AND day IN (?)
              AND metric IN ('Searches_Regular', 
                             'Event_Citation', 
                             'Event_Record_Print',
                             'Event_Record_Views',
                             'Event_Record_Export', 
                             'Event_Record_Save',
                             'Event_Result_Clicks',
                             'Event_Record_Email')
           GROUP BY 
              date, 
              identifier, 
              metric ) as records
   ORDER BY 
      date, 
      identifier, 
      metric
```

I am trying to execute the above query in production application, it's taking more time(10 mins) to execute if we have large amount of data, is there any way to optimize the below query for better performance
version : 5.7
I have created the indexes for all the columns which are involved.

Comment: Please update your question with the detailed EXPLAIN PLAN for your query

Comment: And the `SHOW INDEX` statement is helpful. For a large dataset, cardinality can play an important role in determining how MySQL chooses indexes .

Comment: Better use subquery with JOIN ...

Answer (score 0):

```
day IN (?)
```

What API are you using?  That syntax *may* be replacing `?` with a single string, which won't give the list that you expect.

If `?` is only ever replaced by a single value, then say `day = ?`.

Please avoid `UPPER(x) as x` because:

- It is hard to read, not knowing whether `x` is the original value or the modified value.
- It impedes performance by not allowing an `INDEX` to be used.  Cf [*sargable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)

  DATE_FORMAT(day, '%d %b %Y') as date, day

Can you move the `DATE_FORMAT` to the outer query?  (And change the `GROUP BY` to reference `day`.)

These *may* help:

```
INDEX(product_code, customer_id, day)
```